# Functions of Open AL giving error of undefined reference while compiling with g++ in ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-16.04, openal, openal-soft

I am completely new to Open AL.
So I started with installing Open AL library through command line

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev
```

And also I installed alut installed with this command

```
sudo apt-get install libalut0 libalut-dev
```

Also I forked open Al from http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html
and installed it also.
But when I am trying to compile this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <AL/alut.h>
int main(){
   ALCdevice *device;
   device=alcOpenDevice(NULL);
   if(!device)
   {
       printf("no device found");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("device found");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

/tmp/cchMpaeS.o: In function `main':
altest.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to`alcOpenDevice'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I compiled it with

```
g++ altest.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 altest.cpp
```

Both of them gave same error.

Comment: If you tried something, and you have issue with it, please post what you tried. In this case you tried to compile your program ,but you have not posted the commands you used when you tried that. So post that command.

Comment: @nos I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to the OpenAl library:

```
g++ -std=c++11 altest.cpp -lopenal
```